# Improving tomato sauce in beef liver recipe

Tags: sauce, beef, garlic, liver

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What kind of sauce can I make for beef liver?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/21908/what-kind-of-sauce-can-i-make-for-beef-liver)

I boil the liver in order to be healthier but a own variant is to heat it on a pan afterwards  or fry it with little oil from the beginning. I made sauce using garlic, a bit of onion and tomatoes. However, the tomato puree is too bland and I am not sure if the tomato puree is the best fit. Maybe I should use diced tomato. What can I do to improve my recipe in the sense already described?

Comment: Please do not repost questions. [What can I add to X](http://meta.cooking.stackexchange.com/q/1091/41) questions are also not generally permitted here.

Answer (score 2):

A few finely diced mushrooms or olives can add a lot of extra flavour, Worcester Sauce is of course an option too for quickly adding flavour.

There are quite a few 'proper' recipes which recommend fried and blended celery but I've never found it to work that well, it can add body if thinly sliced but doesn't do much flavour wise.

Personally I'd add a good helping of coarse black pepper and some dried parsley. I've always found simply adding more garlic can add flavour too so you may want to experiment with that too.

If it's specifically more tomato flavour you want then really the only thing you can do is reduce it more.